# Passing values from jframe to java class in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

in netbeans I've got a JFrame and a JavaClass. In my JFrame I have a combobox to select a file that will be used in the operations within the Java class.

Java class:

```
public class WekaTest {
    public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
        BufferedReader inputReader = null;

        try {
            inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Ficheiro " + filename + " não encontrado");
        }

        return inputReader;
    }
```

(...)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JFrame1 form = new JFrame1();
        form.setVisible(true);

        BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("weather.nominal.arff");

        Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

        (...)

    }

}
```

What I need is, from the JFrame's combobox, to select a different datafile to read from. So, as I change the selected item in my combobox, I want to set my datafile as that value.

Here's the JFrame code:

```
public class JFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public JFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }

   (...)                       

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jTextField1.setText(arffComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());;

    }                                        

    private void arffComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

(...)               
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What class has the BufferedReader?  Pass the file name from your Swing code to this class using the constructor or a setter method.

Comment: I didn't get it. Check the post, I edited it and added the BufferedReader definition

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 3) *"Thanks,
Chiapa"*  Don't include sigs. in questions.  They are noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following a `private` (or `public`) member:

```
private BufferedReader datafile = null;
```

Then do the read within the action listener you've assigned to the combobox:

```
private void arffComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String pth = arffComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    datafile = readDataFile(pth);
}
```

Then you can use `datafile` either in the listener or elsewhere as necessary.

Something like that should do what you're after.

**EDIT**

Given the new information, you're probably going to do best with a [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) that subscribes to the `JFrame1` (`form.addPropertyChangeListener`) object and listens to `PropertyChangeEvents` that you fire from within your `arffComboBoxActionPerformed` method.

In the `arffComboBoxActionPerformed`:

```
private void arffComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String pth = arffComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    firePropertyChange('combo_changed', null, pth);
}
```

Then in the `main`:

```
JFrame1 form = new JFrame1();
form.setVisible(true);
form.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
        // Handle the change here

        String pth = (String) pce.getNewValue();
        BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile(pth);

        Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

        (...)
    }

});
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something - even if `readDataFile` is defined in another class, the above should still work, you'd just do `datafile = myclass.readDataFile(pth);`?

Comment: It doesn't work. `datafile = myclass.` and there are no options available.

Comment: See #1 from @Andrew Thompson's comment.  I'm stabbing in the dark without more information.

Comment: *"all the important code"*  I suggested you post an ***SSCCE*** for good reasons.  One of the (many) good reasons is that people with broken code often have *no idea* which parts of the code are relevant.  For your own sake, please actually *read* the document before making random guesses about the meaning of SSCCE.

Comment: In the SSCCE page you provided and I actually read, it clearly suggests people to insert only the relevant parts without code parts that they are SURE that have no influence in the problem. I followed the suggestions in what I read the best I could: I'm sure you are far more experienced than me and are trying to help but pointing fingers isn't a good motivation for learners. Furthermore, what I posted helped @blazetopher find the solution for my specific problem (and he actually helped me out instead of making me feel dumb) so, I guess my indications weren't that bad